# Permanently Enable Keyboard Support For Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

This is driving me a little crazy: I recently installed a Visual Studio update that allowed me to have a bigger-than-normal-version of the Windows Phone emulator running where typing on the computer's physical keyboard was enabled by default; you just start typing on every startup and it works.

However, a recent Windows update (and/or machine restart) seemed to hose something where I'm back to having to press Pause/Break every time I run the emulator in order to enable keyboard support.

My Google searches keep turning up resources like this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff754352(v=vs.105).aspx

Which gives instructions on the Pause/Break approach.

However, I can't seem to find instructions on how to permanently enable keyboard support by default. I know it's possible because I JUST had it set up, but I can't find the switch to flip to revert to those settings.

Comment: Is it Windows Phone 8 or 8.1 emulator? From what I know, the 8.1 emulators support checkpoints to save the state of the emulator. Maybe, you saved the state of the emulator when the virtual keyboard was disabled?

Comment: Looks like it's Windows Phone 8.0 according to a label on the Visual Studio project.